# Distance measure in KNN regression

Tags: regression, k-nearest-neighbour

I am currently reading up on KNN-regression. As I understand it the value of a given response variable $y_{i}$ at some point $(x_{1,i}, x_{2,i}, x_{3,i}...)$ is estimated as the average over the k-nearest neighbor values:

$$
y_{i} = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j}^{k}y_{j}     \ \ \ \ (1), 
$$

with the nearest neighbors determined as those with the smallest generalized euclidean distances to the query point, i.e.

$$
D_{ij} = \sqrt{(x_{1,i} - x_{1,j})^2 + (x_{2,i} - x_{2,j})^2 + (x_{3,i} - x_{3,j})^2 + ...}. (2)
$$

In a real world example the covariates might reflect different properties which are not equally important for explaining the value of the response variable. In the example of predicting a property price, where the covariates are location, building age, building size etc. I might for instance expect that the location should weight more heavily in the distance measure than the building size. Is there a generalized version of KNN, which takes this into account? I am thinking of something along the lines of each term in (2) being scales by some weight $w_{j}$, which should be determined by the algorithm.

I hope the question makes sense!

Comment: the problem is that KNN has an inductive bias that might not be reflected by the algorithm you use to generate the $w_i$

Comment: 1. KNN does not require Euclidean distances, any proper distance will do.  2. You can rescale each variable to, for example, be centered at zero and have an average distance from zero equal to one.  There are other techniques you can use as well, hence the comment nature of this response.